# JSP page not discovering assets when ran in browser

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

I am building a JSP website application with struts using eclipse and tomcat server. I have written my JSP code and added the following code to make my stylesheet visible to the JSP :

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
```

My application looks fine and is styled properly in the web viewing interface of eclipse but when I run it in the browser the styling does not get applied to the page. I think there might be a rooting issue involving because of struts. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Cheers!

Comment: Does the request to the stylesheet result in `404` ?

Comment: In the browser yes, but not in the eclipse internal web browser

Comment: How are you mapping the Disptacher Servlet ? Also check if the URL to stylesheet is correct .

Comment: The URL to the stylesheet is working, could you tell me more about mapping the dispatcher servlet? Thanks

Comment: Which version of struts?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<s:url value='/styles/style.css'/>" />`

This will generate the correct url taking into account the deployment path.